# icarousel is not showing up for ios7

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, icarousel

I want to use icarousel in my project. I've downloaded icarousel from github. When I add icarousel it didn't show up. What might be the reason?

Here is my code:

**PhotoPreview.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iCarousel.h"

@interface PhotoPreview : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource,iCarouselDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) iCarousel *carousel;

@end
```

**PhotoPreview.m**

```
#import "PhotoPreview.h"

@interface PhotoPreview (){
    NSMutableArray *items;
}

@end

@implementation PhotoPreview

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
    [self.view addSubview:_carousel];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        [items addObject:@(i)];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    NSLog(@"%d",items.count);
    return 5;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
        label.tag = 1;
        [view addSubview:label];
    }
    else
    {
        label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
    }
    label.text = @"AAA";
    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    if (option == iCarouselOptionSpacing)
    {
        return value * 1.1f;
    }
    return value;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I explored it few days ago and as I remembered this part was an IBOutlet connected to a view whose class was set to `iCarousel` from Interface builder.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet iCarousel *carousel;
```

Also, there delegates were also connected from IB.

**EDIT:**

Look at you code `viewDidLoad`:

You haven't initialized `_carousel` object, it should be added throught IB. Look at the images i have attached.

**Image1:**

[image]

**Image2:**

[image]

**image3:**

[image]

Also, look at the examples provided with the library.

Hope it helps!

Comment: At first I did as you told. But I can not get this object in IB.

Comment: Take a UIView and set it class to iCarousel.

Comment: No help. I can not set delegate and datasource from IB.